# Android:About ksoap2 and webservice

Tags: android, web-services, wsdl, ksoap2

I get the wsdl and the URL,and the server is written in C++;
I use KSoap2 in android to access the method ,but it always 
prints out :**"Method 'methodname' not implemented"!!!**
Can anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you may not specify method name to be executed.

Comment: @Pro I specify the right method name.But...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see here the simple example of ksoap may help http://vimeo.com/9633556

Comment: @hotverypicy Thanks,does it matter what kind of language the server used?

Comment: ya, definitely suppose if you want to use c,c++ file in android then for that you have to create native library

Comment: @hotverypicy you mean I need to generate the Java code(I use java in android) from wsdl file ?

Comment: it depends, but that is upto you now how you will manage, try buddy

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating your request and the `SoapAction` properly?

Try the example below (it is a public web service with 0 arguments) and see if it works for you.

```
private static final String WSDL_URL = "http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL";
private static final String WS_NAMESPACE = "http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/";
private static final String WS_METHOD_NAME = "GetWeatherInformation";

// 1. Creating SOAP request with no arguments
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(new SoapObject(WS_NAMESPACE, WS_METHOD_NAME));

// 2. Create a HTTP Transport object to send the web service request
HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(WSDL_URL);
httpTransport.debug = true; // allows capture of raw request/respose in Logcat

// 3. Make the web service invocation
httpTransport.call(WS_NAMESPACE + WS_METHOD_NAME, envelope);

Log.d(TAG, "HTTP REQUEST:\n" + httpTransport.requestDump);
Log.d(TAG, "HTTP RESPONSE:\n" + httpTransport.responseDump);
```

Have a look at this detailed tutorial explaining the basics of [using kSOAP2 with Android](http://thiranjith.com/2012/10/15/introduction-to-working-with-ksoap2-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://216.128.29.26/webservices/TempConvert.asmx";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit"
```

you should specify necessary field as above.

Comment: yeah,I just write them as above

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://216.128.29.26/webservices/TempConvert.asmx";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView tv;
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setText(ws());
}
public String ws() {
    String result = "";
    try
    {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("Celsius", "32");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        if(envelope.getResponse()!=null){
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            result = "FeranHit : " + response.toString();
        }   
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        result = e.getMessage();
    }
    return result;
}
```

see this is my code. and m getting full result. This is just test program for ksoap2.

> i have not included any libraries here.

Comment: Thanks Pro.But I really have written the code like yours.But it just cannot work.I change the methodName to the <element name="xxRequest"> (but not <operation name="xx">),it GOD works.Why? PS:I use"....?wsdl"

Comment: Help Never Hurts.. :)                              Now which kind of error you are getting? can you please tell?